# Must declare the scalar variable "@cnt"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please see the code below:

```
declare @Classification as varchar(5)
set @Classification =''
declare @ClassificationSQL as nvarchar(4000)
declare @PersonSQL as nvarchar(4000)
set @ClassificationSQL=''

declare @counts int

DECLARE NicheDeletionOffenderCursor CURSOR FOR  
    select classification from dbnicheoffenderclassificationlookup
    Open NicheDeletionOffenderCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM NicheDeletionOffenderCursor INTO @Classification

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
    If @ClassificationSQL=''
        set @ClassificationSQL='classification like ' + char(39) + '%' + @Classification + '%' + char(39)
    else
        set @ClassificationSQL=@ClassificationSQL + ' OR classification like ' + char(39) + '%' + @Classification + '%' + char(39)
    FETCH NEXT FROM NicheDeletionOffenderCursor INTO @Classification
    END
CLOSE NicheDeletionOffenderCursor 
DEALLOCATE NicheDeletionOffenderCursor 

SET @ClassificationSQL = 'select @cnt=count(*) from tbl_goccivgperson where lid=@LID and (' + @ClassificationSQL + ')' 
SET @PersonSQL = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_goccivgperson WHERE LID=@LID and (' + @ClassificationSQL + ')' 

DECLARE @CoreSystemIndexValue varchar(100)
SET @CoreSystemIndexValue=''

DECLARE NicheDeletionCursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT TOP 1 coresystemindexvalue from dbdisposals where datasetname='NICHECI'

    Open NicheDeletionCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM NicheDeletionCursor INTO @CoreSystemIndexValue
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @ClassificationSQL, N'@LID decimal(25,0),@cnt int OUTPUT', @LID=@CoreSystemIndexValue, @cnt=@Counts OUTPUT 'Line 38
            --If @Counts > 0
                --begin
                    --Check that all the nominals in Niche are ready for deletion
                    EXECUTE sp_executesql @PersonSQL, N'@LID decimal(25,0)', @LID=@CoreSystemIndexValue 'Line 42
                --end
            --Else
                --Check that all Persons (all are RCWs) in CIS and Niche are ready for deletion

        FETCH NEXT FROM NicheDeletionCursor INTO @CoreSystemIndexValue
        END
    CLOSE NicheDeletionCursor

DEALLOCATE NicheDeletionCursor
```

The error I get is: Must declare the scalar variable "@cnt".  Commenting out either line 38 or lin2 42 resolved the problem.  The problem seems to be with line 42.  There is not reference to: @cnt in @PersonSQL so I cannot see why I am getting the problem.

Comment: Where have you declared it? I can see the assignment using count but not the declaration.

Comment: Don't you have to declare `@cnt` at the top?

Comment: It is declared as part of the dynamic sql rather than at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this code

```
SET @ClassificationSQL = 'select @cnt=count(*) from tbl_goccivgperson where lid=@LID and (' + @ClassificationSQL + ')' 
SET @PersonSQL = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_goccivgperson WHERE LID=@LID and (' + @ClassificationSQL + ')'
```

That uses the `@ClassificationSQL` variable in the `@PersonSQL` calculation, so `@cnt` ends up there as well. I think what you want to do is actually

```
SET @PersonSQL = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_goccivgperson WHERE LID=@LID and (' + @ClassificationSQL + ')' 
SET @ClassificationSQL = 'select @cnt=count(*) from tbl_goccivgperson where lid=@LID and (' + @ClassificationSQL + ')'
```

or better yet, do not reuse the `@ClassificationSQL` variable

```
declare @ClassificationSQL as nvarchar(4000)
declare @PersonSQL as nvarchar(4000)
declare @ConditionSQL as nvarchar(4000) --or a name that makes sense

-- calculate @ConditionSQL 

SET @ClassificationSQL = 'select @cnt=count(*) from tbl_goccivgperson where lid=@LID and (' + @ConditionSQL  + ')' 
SET @PersonSQL = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_goccivgperson WHERE LID=@LID and (' + @ConditionSQL + ')'
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a silly mistake. +1. I will mark this answer when the time limit expires.